# If Then to Loop through Pivot Items

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I'm stuck on this issue and cannot figure out what it is I am doing wrong. I'm in the process of writing a macro to loop through visible fields in a pivot table, find the items in those fields that are filtered, and then apply those filters to the source data table. The particular problem I'm having deals with a loop that is supposed to look in a field, find the visible pivot items, and then store those items as variables. I've been messing around with trying to terminate the loop if all pivot items are visible. Below is what I have so far:

```
Sub PivotTest2()
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim count As Integer
Dim available As Integer
Dim row As Integer


available = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Cities").PivotFields("City").PivotItems.count
row = 2 'This is your starting row for display


    For Each pi In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Cities").PivotFields("City").PivotItems
        If pi.Visible Then
        count = count + 1
        End If
        If count = available Then
            MsgBox ("All Pivot Items Are Selected")
        End If
        If count <> available Then
            row = row + 1
        Range("'Sheet4'!G" & row) = pi.Name
        End If
    Next pi
End Sub
```

So whenever I have a filter on a city, or group of cities, the macro pastes them to a range in the spreadsheet. Eventually, I want to store them as variables, but for now I'm just pasting them for the purposes of working through the code. You can also see that when the number of visible items is equal to the total number of pivot items in that field, I'm returning a message box. Eventually, that message box will go away and be replaced by code that tells it to start looking through pivot items in the next visible field.

I realize that this might be unnecessary, as applying all visible items as filters to the source data field would result in all items being shown, which accomplishes the same thing. However, I'm more curious about what it is I'm doing wrong at this point. The code pastes all items to the range, regardless of whether there is a filter or not. However, the message box only returns when there is no filter applied, so it appears to be working correctly.

Any input/feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that part of your checks should be outside your loop which determines the amount of visible `PivotItems`.

At first, I'd suggest to move the `Next pi` after the first `If`-`End If` block. Your `count` variable should then contain the number of visible items. If all items are visible, your message box should then appear. However, for the second part (copying visible items), you'd need to loop again.

To avoid the second loop, you may want to copy the `pi.Name` values to a temporary range, and copy this range to the final range only if there are filters applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For Each pi In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Cities").PivotFields("City").PivotItems
    If pi.Visible Then
        count = count + 1
        Range("'Sheet4'!G" & row) = pi.Name
        row = row + 1
    End If
Next pi
If count = available Then
    MsgBox ("All Pivot Items Are Selected")
End If
```

Your code doesn't check if the city is visible before pasting, which is why it always pastes every city name.